# What i did wrong in my python function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def make_str_from_row(board, row_index):

    ''' (list of list of str, int) -> str

    Return the characters from the row of the board with index row_index
    as a single string.

    >>> make_str_from_row([['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']], 0)
    'ANTT'
    '''
    for i in range(len(board)):
        i = row_index
        print(board[i])
```

This prints `['A', 'N', 'T', 'T']`

How do I print it like this `'ANTT'` instead?

Comment: Your indention is wrong. Use four spaces.

Comment: The line `i = row_index` is weird. Did you mean `if i == row_index:`?

Comment: @0605002: That would also be wierd

Comment: @0605002: Why would you loop over all values of `i` when you do nothing on all but one value?

Comment: @Eric Haha, yes! I was a bit late to get that.

Comment: Thnaks for all that helped me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you got what you told to print!

`board` is a list of list of `str`s, so `board[i]` must be a list of `str`s, and when you write `print(board[i])`, you get a list!

You may need to write this:

```
print(''.join(board[i]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify that a whole lot by using

```
>>> def make_str_from_row(board, row_index):
...     print repr(''.join(board[row_index]))
... 
>>> make_str_from_row([['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']], 0)
'ANTT'
```

The reason you get that output is because you print a list since the elements of board are lists. By using `join`, you get a string.

Also, I don't understand why you use a loop if are going to change the index you loop over.

Comment: i try what you writed .. it result in ANTT instead 'ANTT' ... the '' have to apper

Comment: You could use `repr` for that. Reflected that in the answer.

Comment: @FelipeGaldino: This is almost certainly not what you want. I suspect you are supposed to `return row`, not `print repr(row)`

Comment: @Eric: That was my guess as well, but you know how they say: the customer is always right. Or?

Answer (score 0):

I think this was what you were trying to do:

```
def make_str_from_row(board, row_index):
    ''' (list of list of str, int) -> str

    Return the characters from the row of the board with index row_index
    as a single string.

    >>> make_str_from_row([['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']], 0)
    'ANTT'
    '''
    for cell in board[row_index]:
        print cell,
```